# Why is inorder tree traversal without recursion in Python running infinitely?

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-tree, tree-traversal, inorder

I'm trying to do Inorder tree traversal for binary trees without using recursion but it seems like the while loop keeps running infinitely. Any help would be appreciated.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.data = data


def inOrder(root):
    s = []
    while s is not None or root is not None:
        if root is not None:
            s.append(root.left)
            if root.left:
                root = root.left
        else:
            root = s.pop()
            print(root.data)
            if root.right:
                root = root.right


if __name__=='__main__':

    root = Node(5)
    root.left = Node(3)
    root.left.right = Node(2)
    root.left.left = Node(4)
    root.right = Node(10)
    root.right.left = Node(9)
    root.right.right = Node(20)

#            5 
#          /   \ 
#         3     10 
#       /  \   /  \
#      4    2 9    20

    inOrder(root)
```

Comment: Not a solution, but `s` will never be `None`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the following code for inorder traversal:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.data = data


def inOrder(root):
    s = []
    s.append(root)
    while len(s) > 0: # Check if stack is not empty
        if root.left: #Case 1: Traverse left if there is an element left of the current root
            s.append(root.left)
            root = root.left
        else:
            root = s.pop() #Case 2: If there is no element on the left, print the current root
            print(root.data)
            if root.right: #Case 3: If there is an element on the right, traverse right of the current root
                s.append(root.right)
                root = root.right


if __name__=='__main__':

    root = Node(5)
    root.left = Node(3)
    root.left.right = Node(2)
    root.left.left = Node(4)
    root.right = Node(10)
    root.right.left = Node(9)
    root.right.right = Node(20)
    inOrder(root)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is correct but the problem is that

```
s is not None
```

Is not the same as

```
s!=[]
```

Your s is a stack which is always there and you actually want to check whether your stack is empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

You are always initiating `s` to an empty list, which will never be `None`. You wanted to check whether `not s`, not whether `s is not None`.

Comment: I didn’t append the initial root node as well, which the other answer pointed out. Had to select it as the correct one. However, thanks a lot for your help.